# Idiomatic boolean equality usage (singletons)

Tags: haskell, dependent-type, singleton-type

I want to create a data structure to store items tagged on type level using Symbol. This:

```
data Store e (ss :: [Symbol]) where
  Nil :: Store e '[]
  Cons :: e s -> Store e ss -> Store e (s ': ss)

data HasElem (a :: k) (as :: [k]) where
  AtHead :: HasElem a (a ': as)
  InTail :: HasElem a as -> HasElem a (b ': as)

class HasElemC (a :: k) (as :: [k]) where hasElem :: HasElem a as
instance HasElemC {OVERLAPPING} a (a ': as) where hasElem = AtHead
instance HasElemC a as => HasElemC a (b ': as) where hasElem = InTail hasElem

from :: HasElemC s ss => Store e ss -> e s
from = from' hasElem

from' :: HasElem s ss -> Store e ss -> e s
-- from' _ Nil = undefined
from' h (Cons element store) = case h of
  AtHead -> element
  InTail h' -> from' h' store
```

kinda works, if you neglect the fact that compiler warns me for not supplying `from' _ Nil` definition (why does it, by the way? is there a way to make it stop?) But what I really wanted to do in the beginning was to use singletons library in idiomatic fashion, instead of writing my own type-level code. Something like this:

```
import Data.Singletons.Prelude.List

data Store e (ss :: [Symbol]) where
  Nil :: Store e '[]
  Cons :: Sing s -> e s -> Store e ss -> Store e (s ': ss)

from :: Elem s ss ~ True => Store e ss -> e s
from (Cons evidence element nested) = ???
```

Sadly I could not figure out how to convert the context to a propositional equality. How can you use building blocks from singletons library to do what I'm trying to do?

ghc@7.10.3, singletons@2.1

Comment: You can remove the warning in `from'` by adding functions `storeHead :: Store e (s ': ss) -> e s` and `storeTail :: Store e (s ': ss) -> Store e ss` and use them on the store after you've matched `AtHead` or `InTail`.

Comment: Your two `HasElemC` instances overlap. GHC will find it impossible to discharge a `HasElemC` constraint because it doesn't check preconditions when doing proof search. Fortunately there's [a well-known trick using type families and `UndecidableInstances`](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/AdvancedOverlap). (In fact this is one of the few good uses of Boolean type families.)

Comment: Thank you cchalmers, that worked.

Thanks, Benjamin. Overlaps are fine in my case: I don't need functions polymorphic in ss. Although I might need them in the future.

Comment: @NioBium I think you're misunderstanding me: `HasElemC` is _useless_ because of the way you've defined your instances. Try writing `x = HasElem "a" '["a"]; x = hasElem`. It won't type-check.

Comment: No, I understand you. My code using `from` does type-check and runs correctly. You just need to mark AtHead instance OVERLAPPING/InTail instance OVERLAPPABLE. Are you saying it shouldn't?

Comment: NioBium, I think maybe @BenjaminHodgson may just dislike overlapping instances sufficiently that he's not tried too hard to learn how to use them; it's very often better to learn how *not* to. The type family trick will be pickier, unfortunately. For example, the type family thing will refuse to select an instance using a polymorphic inequality like `a /~ (q ': a)` because type families can represent infinite types. Overlapping instances will happily do so because it doesn't affect type safety.

Answer (score 8):

[Don't use Booleans](https://existentialtype.wordpress.com/2011/03/15/boolean-blindness/)! I seem to [keep](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37925725/1523776) [repeating](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38221146/1523776) [myself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33270639/so-whats-the-point) on this point: Booleans are of extremely limited usefulness in dependently-typed programming and the sooner you un-learn the habit the better.

An `Elem s ss ~ True` context promises to you that `s` is in `ss` somewhere, but it doesn't say *where*. This leaves you in the lurch when you need to produce an `s`-value from your list of `ss`. One bit is not enough information for your purposes.

Compare this with the computational usefulness of your original `HasElem` type, which is structured like a natural number giving the index of the element in the list. (Compare the shape of a value like `There (There Here)` with that of `S (S Z)`.) To produce an `s` from a list of `ss` you just need to dereference the index.

That said, you should still be able to *recover* the information you threw away and extract a `HasElem x xs` value from a context of `Elem x xs ~ True`. It's tedious, though - you have to search the list for the item (*which you already did* in order to evaluate `Elem x xs`!) and eliminate the impossible cases. Working in Agda (definitions omitted):

```
recover : {A : Set}
          (_=?_ : (x : A) -> (y : A) -> Dec (x == y))
          (x : A) (xs : List A) ->
          (elem {{_=?_}} x xs == true) ->
          Elem x xs
recover _=?_ x [] ()
recover _=?_ x (y :: ys) prf with x =? y
recover _=?_ x (.x :: ys) prf | yes refl = here
recover _=?_ x (y :: ys) prf | no p = there (recover _=?_ x ys prf)
```

All this work is unnecessary, though. Just use the information-rich proof-term to start with.

---

By the way, you should be able to stop GHC warning you about incomplete patterns by doing your `Elem` matching on the left hand side, rather than in a `case`-expression:

```
from' :: HasElem s ss -> Store e ss -> e s
from' AtHead (Cons element store) = element
from' (InTail i) (Cons element store) = from' i store
```

By the time you're on the right-hand side of a definition, it's too late for pattern-matching to refine the possible constructors for other terms on the left.

Comment: Thank you. I was just trying not to invent the wheel. Still hoping someone would provide a solution in Haskell singletons, if one exists. What's the point in lifting all of those functions to type-level, if you can't use them in proofs?

Comment: Well, singletons are (and `singletons` is) one particular mode of use of GADTs and data-kinds. Proof-terms like `Elem` are another. They don't naturally fit into the singleton framework because they're not singletons!